# Beyond provide a profile of an instance's stack, what is the purpose of Connections?

Tags: settings, admin, administer

I am seeking information about the Connections admin area (Administer>System Settings>Connections):
[image]

I have seen in one instance that there is something that can be set up here to generate a site profile that provides info about the instance without exposing sensitive info like filepaths. I can see how this is useful but it seems oddly placed and like there could be more to it.

Is there anything else that can be set up using this function? I have searched in documentation and not found any info. I am very curious (on behalf of a client) about what this is and what its uses are.

Answer (score 3):

It is described a little bit here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16173

Seems like the intent is a generic framework. I believe this link is a reference implementation of how to write a service that would interact with this framework: https://github.com/civicrm/cxnapp

Maybe others know of some real services that do implement this.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! I was able to then improve my search terms (CiviConnect rather than CiviConnections) and find this blog post, which provides context: https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/toward-civiconnect

Comment: Ah yes good find.