# What does CiviConnect do? ("Connections" in the System menu)

Tags: integration

I found this old blog post: https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/toward-civiconnect

> The CiviConnect initiative aims to provide an alternative to the scavenger hunt while preserving Civi's core values (Free/Libre Software, data ownership, on-site deployment, etc).  How?  By providing a simple, secure mechanism for finding and connecting supplemental services.

This sounds like something I'd be interested in learning more about, but the page itself provides little guidance except for an error: "CRL distributor has an invalid certificate"

[image: Screenshot]

What should I be seeing on this page? I can't say I've ever looked here before.

Comment: Similar question https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28866/beyond-provide-a-profile-of-an-instances-stack-what-is-the-purpose-of-connecti